# double array trie vs triple array trie

Tags: data-structures

I'm reading this post: https://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/, in the beginning of section `Double-Array Trie`, it says

```
The tripple-array structure for implementing trie appears to be well defined, 
but is still not practical to keep in a single file. 
The next/check pool may be able to keep in a single array of integer couples, 
but the base array does not grow in parallel to the pool, 
and is therefore usually split.
```

What does `the base array is usually split` mean and why?

I'd like to understand what is the benefits to use double array trie instead of triple array trie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer partially to you question.

In a triple array trie we've three array: base, next and check. the base array contains the distinct state of the trie. In the next array we have all the state stored many times: one time when they are the start state and the others each time another state transitions to them. The check have the ownership of a transition.

One way to model a trie with a triple array  is model a structure with three array: base, next and check. This is a basic implemantion.

```
trie {
  base:  array<S>;
  next:  array<S>;
  check: array<S>;
}
```

Because next and check have meaningful data, state and ownership, for a transion at the same index we can model these data in a pair. So the data structure has two array: the base array and the pair array, containg the next and check data in one place.

```
trie {
  base: array<S>;
  transition: array<Pair>;
}

Pair {
  next:  array<S>;
  check: array<S>;
}
```

We can have this implementation to:

```
trie {  
  transition: array<Triple>;
}

Triple {
  base: array<S>;
  next:  array<S>;
  check: array<S>;
}
```

This is a bad implementation because it seems like the first, but base array data are duplicated for each transition.

In second implementation, where base split from next and check, we can retrieve next and check data at the same time and we doesn't duplicate base info like in the third.

In two-array next is called base and base is dropped away because it is not really necessary. It stores and manages data and this is a something valuable.

Comment: Now I understand what does `split` mean. There is still one thing, I thought the start state is not stored in the `next` array, the start state is an index and is virtual.

Comment: I do some seach and I've discovered a couple of useful resources: The first https://www.slideshare.net/jnory/dalm-emnlp-27373037 tells us that in two-array trie the root node is at 0 position in arrays and that the position of the words are based on unigram probability. The second https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model#Unigram tell how unigram probability works.